# PostgreSQL time difference in minutes from time column?

Tags: postgresql

I want to calculate time duration in minutes using PostgreSQL (phone calls).

-- Difference between  08:54:55 and  08:56:10  (time only)

SELECT DATE_PART('hour', '08:56:10'::time - '08:54:55'::time) * 60 +
        DATE_PART('minute', '08:56:10'::time - '08:54:55'::time);
-- Result: 1

How can I modify this to work for the whole dataset? Start time (only hour and minute, seconds are always 00) and end time are in the same column Event_Time, grouped by Correlation_ID.

```
Event_Time  Customer_ID Case_ID Event_ID    Correlation_ID  Line_ID Internal_ID
10:11:00            id1     1       start       sd34        l3      456
10:13:00            id5     8       stop        rt56        l3      456
10:15:00            id4     3       start       tg84        l7      567
10:17:00            id7     5       start       ty69        l4      678
10:21:00            id5     5       stop        rt56        l7      678
10:31:00            id1     1       stop        sd34        l4      567
```

I tried this solution, but it works only when I specify time http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff.

Thanks!

Comment: please add more details to your question. Read this for tips on how to ask better sql questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: Thanks! Just added more info to my question.

Comment: I'm assuming the column `"Event_Time"` is a time column (not some sort of string)

Answer (score 1):

perhaps with a self join like this:

```
SELECT
  start."Correlation_ID",
  extract(epoch from stop."Event_time" - start."Event_time")/60
FROM
  some_table AS start
JOIN
  some_table AS stop
  ON start."Correlation_ID"=finish."Correlation_ID"
  AND stop."Event_ID"='stop'
WHERE 
  start."Event_ID"='start'
;
```

or with a group like this:

```
SELECT
  "Correlation_ID",
  extract(epoch from 
     max(CASE "Event_ID" WHEN 'stop' THEN "Event_time" END ) 
    -min(CASE "Event_ID" WHEN 'start' THEN "Event_time" END ) 
    ) /60
FROM
  some_table
JOIN
  grouP BY "Correlation_ID"
;
```